# Getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error" while trying to send push notification to APNS using notnoop library

Tags: java, ios, ssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send push notification using notnoop java library but i am receiving SSL exception. I have also tried to search the solution online and took help of some online tools, but in vain.

I tried "http://pushtry.com/" which is showing SSPI error and "http://www.pushwatch.com/apns/" showing "[Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14094438:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert internal error".

I do not have idea on ios but i want the solution for a project.

Scenario: External java server should send push notification to particular ios app.

My Code:

```
import com.notnoop.apns.APNS;
import com.notnoop.apns.ApnsService;
import com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification;

public class ApnsTest {

    private ApnsService service;

    public ApnsTest() {
        try {
            String certPath = "certification_ios.p12";
            File certFile = new File(certPath);
            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(certFile);
            service = APNS.newService().withCert(fis,"password").withSandboxDestination().build();
            sendMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ApnsTest();
    }

    public void sendMessage() {
        String payload=APNS.newPayload().alertBody("").sound("default").build();
        String deviceToken ="devicetokenof64characters";
        int now = (int) (new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        EnhancedApnsNotification notification = new EnhancedApnsNotification(EnhancedApnsNotification.INCREMENT_ID(),
                now + 60 * 60, deviceToken, payload);

        System.out.println("Sending push notification");
        service.push(deviceToken, payload);
    }

}
```

The full stacktrace of the exception i am getting is below:

```
com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.wrapAndThrowAsRuntimeException(Utilities.java:277)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:257)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:46)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:56)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:45)
    at ApnsTest.sendMessage(ApnsTest.java:47)
    at ApnsTest.<init>(ApnsTest.java:24)
    at ApnsTest.main(ApnsTest.java:31)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:240)
    ... 8 more
```

What am i missing or doing wrong?

Password is correct and device token provided is also a valid one.

Comment: I got the solution. The code works fine. The problem was while creating the certificate. Thanks to anyone who tried to help. :-)

Comment: Hi user2708129, Could please let share the problem with certificate creation. I am facing the same issue here, created the certificate n times and no luck yet. What do I need to do extra while creating the cert?